# How to show upcoming events in the current month with calendar module?

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm using Drupal 7 Module Calendar, Views and Panels.

I used the block-mini-calendar view of Calendar module to display on my frontpage.

Then I created a custom view to display only a list of the day's events selected by the user.

I put as Context-Filter: 
`Date: Date (node​​) (Content: Dates - start date (event_calendar_date)`)

```
And Filter Criteria:
Content: Published (Yes)
Content: Type (= Event Calendar)
```

Then, I created a panel-page that receive the arguments of the date by URL and passes to my view created (My view created above I've put in my panel created with the URL of events/%date).

All previous flow works well. I'm listing all events of the day selected by the user. But, I need to display all events that are within the range of parameter passed in the URL(day selected) and the last day of the current month that the user is.

What changes should I do in my view?

Sorry for my english. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try paginating the view by Date,I guess should get the month options in the pagination as well.I do not have a drupal set up with calendar so can not confirm, you have to give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module, you can add a filter for the current date using relative values.

```
number space? (unit | 'week')
```

Add two Date filters, each for the event date.

- Value is **greater than or equal to** "-15 days"
- Value is **less than or equal to** "+15 days"

Basically we're saying to give us all events that have a date within 15 days of us, behind us and ahead of us. You can increase/decrease those values as needed.